# Odometer fails to load only in OBS

Tags: javascript, html, css, obs, odometer

I have a website that uses hubspot's odometers. Everything works fine when the user visits a website from a browser, however, if user adds browser source in OBS, some of the odometers refuse to load and therefore show pure numbers only.

This is how my website looks like in browser:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEVFh.png)

And this is how my website looks like in OBS: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v6WL.png)

I've searched the whole internet but I couldn't find the answer, unfortunately.
If it matters, my website is https://livecounts.io

Comment: If it helps, open your website in Chrome and you see the same as what you're experiencing in OBS

Comment: Nope, everything works fine on Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

So after trying with difference odometer versions, I've decided just to switch odometer updating method from JQuery to pure Javascript and it fixed the issue.